# "Has much nature" or "is very green"

Tags: expressions

If we want to say that

> Our college has a lot of trees and flowers

in a somewhat abstract manner, which is better?

> Our college has much nature.
>
> There is much nature in our college.
>
> Our college is very green.

Is there any appropriate expression?

According to a book, when *nature* is used without an article, the word means *a wild nature*. Therefore, you should use *be very green*.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question in your question? If so, do you really have a question?

Comment: Sorry, my English is strange. The book says "you should use "be very green"". But I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm not sure whether the book is right or not. So is the description of the book is right? (Do you agree with this book?) Or is there any appropriate expression?

Comment: The book is not correct.  You can use nature.  "To be green" means to be environmentally conscious, not specifically to be surrounded by nature.  Wild nature is called wilderness.

Answer (score 1):

"Our college is very green .. " is ambiguous. Some readers would interpret this as meaning the college is eco-friendly.

You could say: "Our college is set in nature .." (or "surrounded by nature").

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm afraid that the expressions do not mean that "The inside of our college has a lot of trees and flowers".

Answer (score 1):

The sense of "be very green" that's most likely to occur to many people today is environmental sensitivity (or, eco-friendly, per previous answer).  Of course the phrase can be used to say that a college has many trees and flowers, but that meaning is a ways down the list of possible meanings of "very green college", which include an inexperienced faculty or student body, a bilious group of people, and high frequency of green-colored buildings.

If you add 'campus' or 'grounds' after 'college', to indicate that you are talking about the outdoor appearance of the school, rather than about people, then confusion is less likely.

"Our college has much nature" and "There is much nature in our college" sound stilted and awkward.  Perhaps refer to 'many natural features' instead of 'much nature'.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then, how would you express this meaning?

Comment: The phrase "full of greenery" is less ambiguous than "very green". That's what I would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to stick to simple words, you could say:

> Our campus is very [verdant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verdant?show=0&t=1318944202).

Comment: OK, but if someone just learning English says "Our campus is very verdant," what will others think of that?

Answer (score 0):

If I were trying for one noun, I'd probably go for "Our college grounds are full of greenery." Alternatively,

However, even that's a little awkward, so I'd probably go with "Our college has many lawns, gardens, and trees" or something similar.